# Interpretation of predictive posterior distribution

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

I have been trying to undertsand predictive posterior distribution.The following expression is given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71033/what-is-the-difference-between-posterior-and-posterior-predictive-distribution?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

$p(x^*|x)=\int_\Theta c\times p(x^*,\theta|x)d\theta=\int_\Theta c\times p(x^*|\theta)p(\theta|x)d\theta$

I understand that the conditional probability is defined as

$f(A|B)=\frac{f(A,B)}{f(B)} = \frac{f(B|A)*f(A)}{f(B)}$

Can someone explain how the predictive posterior distribution is written using conditional probability?

Comment: No, I am not able to understand how the expression for predictive posterior distribution is written

Comment: What exactly is that you don't understand? The quote gives what you seem to be asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the predictive posterior distribution as

$\begin{aligned}
p(x^*|x) &= \int_{\Theta} p(x^*,\theta|x)d\theta \qquad ``\text{marginalizing out" }\theta\\
& = \int_{\Theta}p(x^*|\theta,x)p(\theta|x)d\theta \qquad \text{conditional probability rule: } P(A,B) = P(A|B) P(B)\\
&= \int_{\Theta}p(x^*|\theta)p(\theta|x)d\theta \qquad x^*\text{ is conditionally independent from }x \text{ given }\theta
\end{aligned}$

where $p(\theta|x)$ is the posterior distribution of $\theta$.

The posterior predictive distribution will depend only on known quantities (the observed data $x$ and some prior's parameters).